# How to use split function in mysql or store split value in different column?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
String x "3_SJ454FH";
```

I want to store '3'(Before _ ) in one column and 'SJ454FH'(After _ ) in another column in mysql. I have tried substring_index function in stored procedure but it did not work. So Is there any way to store value like this in stored procedure.?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_csv`(_list MEDIUMTEXT)
BEGIN

DECLARE _next TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _nextlen INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE _value TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

iterator:
LOOP
  -- exit the loop if the list seems empty or was null;
  -- this extra caution is necessary to avoid an endless loop in the proc.
  IF LENGTH(TRIM(_list)) = 0 OR _list IS NULL THEN
    LEAVE iterator;
  END IF;

  -- capture the next value from the list
  SET _next = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_list,'_',1);

  -- save the length of the captured value; we will need to remove this
  -- many characters + 1 from the beginning of the string 
  -- before the next iteration
  SET _nextlen = LENGTH(_next);

  -- trim the value of leading and trailing spaces, in case of sloppy CSV strings
  SET _value = TRIM(_next);

  -- insert the extracted value into the target table
  INSERT INTO t1 (c1) VALUES (_value);

  -- rewrite the original string using the `INSERT()` string function,
  -- args are original string, start position, how many characters to remove, 
  -- and what to "insert" in their place (in this case, we "insert"
  -- an empty string, which removes _nextlen + 1 characters)
  SET _list = INSERT(_list,1,_nextlen + 1,'');

END LOOP;

END
```

Output:

```
id|c1
-----------
1 |3
-----------
2 |SJ454FH
-----------
```

I have tried this code but it store in next row.

Comment: Edit the question to add your attempted stored procedure.

Comment: Can you see my edited question?

Comment: Is there a column c2 also in table t1 ?

Comment: No but I have tried it by adding c2 column in table. I dont know how it work after adding c2 column in table

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic of the following query in combination with INTO to fill two variables with the desired values and then INSERT them in a separate call.

```
SELECT LEFT("3_SJ454FH", INSTR("3_SJ454FH", "_")-1) AS Prefix, 
       MID("3_SJ454FH", INSTR("3_SJ454FH", "_")+1, LENGTH("3_SJ454FH")) AS Tail
```